# Reload data in swift, of a tableview every 30 seconds

Tags: swift, time, background, refresh

So I have a table that takes some data from my data base and displays it in his cells. I made a refresh button that reloads my code so the user can be able to see the new entries that somebody added into the data base, when you tap it.

This is how the code of my refresh button looks like:

```
 @IBAction func refreshButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        textArray.removeAllObjects()

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Conversation", predicate: predicate)

        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

        publicCloudDatabase?.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil,
            completionHandler: ({results, error in

                if (error != nil) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.notifyUser("Cloud Access Error",
                            message: error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } else {
                    if results.count > 0 {
                        var record = results[0] as! CKRecord
                        self.currentRecord = record

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            for x in results{
                                self.textArray.addObject(x.objectForKey("message") as! String)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.notifyUser("No Match Found",
                                message: "No record matching the address was found")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }))
    }
```

I'd like to remove that button and make a refresh of the table every 30 seconds (in the background of the app - i don't want the user to be aware of it), it is that possible ? If yes, how can it be done?
 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using timers is one way you can achieve,
In ViewDidload

```
self.myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 30.0, target: self, selector: "refresh", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(self.myTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

func refresh() {
    // a refresh of the table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.performQuery every 30s.

2.compare the different between old datas and new datas.

3.Insert the different part by  using this Api

- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

rather than  reloadData